# Is it possible to create a back button for a javascript/HTML slideshow/carousel?

Tags: javascript, html, css

I should say, I am a beginner. I'm still learning javascript. I have a rather large slideshow type site. All the slides are on one html page so I can't use the browser back function. Each slide has a back button. I can't specifically specify where that back button should go because the slide show is non-linear. So I could arrive at any particular slide from any other slide. Is there a way of making a history array or anything that I could use for this back button that would function as a back button? I'm trying to do this purely in javascript/html/css.

Here is a basic version of my setup:
https://jsfiddle.net/jthd0zqt/1/

I've got the back button working in javascript, but only one step backwards. I just made it so each button clicked updates a variable with the current slide's ID. Then the back button just "points" to that variable. The problem is, it won't go back more than one step because once you go back once the variable is never updated to the ID that you just went back from. Hope that makes sense.

```
var slideIndex = 1;
showDivs(slideIndex);

function plusDivs(n) {
  showDivs(slideIndex += n);
}

function currentDiv(n) {
  if (isNaN(n)) {
    var slides = document.getElementsByClassName("mySlides");
    var found = 0;
    for (var i = 0; i < slides.length; i++) {
      if (slides[i].getAttribute("name") == n) {
        found = i + 1;
        break;
      }
    }
    if (!found) return;
    n = found;
  }
  showDivs(slideIndex = n);
}

function plusDivs(n) {
  showDivs(slideIndex += n);
}   

function showDivs(n) {
  var i;
  var x = document.getElementsByClassName("mySlides");
  var dots = document.getElementsByClassName("demo");
  if (n > x.length) {slideIndex = 1}
  if (n < 1) {slideIndex = x.length}
  for (i = 0; i < x.length; i++) {
     x[i].style.display = "none";
  }
  for (i = 0; i < dots.length; i++) {
     dots[i].className = dots[i].className.replace(" opacity-off", "");
  }
  x[slideIndex-1].style.display = "block";
  dots[slideIndex-1].className += " opacity-off";
}
```

For some reason the code works fine in dreamweaver but doesn't work in jsfiddle.

Comment: I'm not seeing where the slides are randomly chosen, but can't you just create an array of all the slide IDs, randomized of course, and then use that to travel back and forth?

Comment: I forgot to add in extra buttons on my example. On most of the slides there are more than just two buttons linking to other slides. I updated my jsfiddle to show this a little better. 

https://jsfiddle.net/jthd0zqt/1/

Answer (score 2):

Yes, it is possible. What you need to look at is the `popstate` event. Some really great documentation with examples can be found at https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/Events/popstate. You'll have to find where this works best into your own code, but this is your start-point.

Comment: Thanks for your reply. This looks like a good starting point. I tried to get it to work with my code but I couldn't. I'll keep trying though!